# Linux is there a way to wait for a file to be created to make a symlink

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, ffmpeg

This question will seems very weird, please take the time to read

1- I have a .sh containing a ffmpeg command (this commands works, here it's all ok)

2- I trigger the .sh via a API call to start recording (all good here too)

3- the ffmpeg start generating the .mp4

4- I want to symlink the .mp4 to .m3u8 (because safari won't read .mp4 as a manifest)

** You probably wondering : why not just changing the ffmpeg in the .sh to output .m3u8

***** **I did try that** but for UNKNOWN reasons the script don't like ANY extension except .mp4

***** If I output .mov .mkv .m3u8 => I don't know why, but it stops after 10 seconds :(

***** The solution I found is to let ffmpeg create the .mp4 and then create a symlink to .m3u8 so hls.js can make it play in all browser including safari...

I'm looking for a way to wait for this .mp4 to exists before creating a symlink.

I tested to create the symlink before with `ln -s fileThatDontExistsYet.mp4 NewFile.m3u8` but when trying to access NewFile.m3u8 result in a 404 not found.... If I manually wait for .mp4 and then do the same command => it works.

so in this odd situation, I found that sleep x seconds before creating the symlink is risky and not very good practice... is there a way via linux command to loop until the file arrives to symlink it ?

-------- EDIT 1 ----------------

CONTEXT :
SERVER1 => website
SERVER2 => openvidu running with docker

-1- a user creates a chatroom (SERVER2)
-2- SERVER2 sends a webhook to SERVER1 telling a session began
-3- then, a API call : SERVER1 tells SERVER2 to records and composed.sh is triggered ---- ALSO : SERVER1 waits x seconds and remote ssh to create the symlink
-4- the .sh launch ffmpeg
-5- the ffmpeg creates the .mp4 while the chat is going on
-6- my modification (see below) is to generate a HLS format stream
-7- other users access to the .m3u8 via their browser (the page have hls.js to play the .m3u8) {SERVER1}
-8- I can achieve 4 seconds delay for the stream which is not bad ;)

The link to view the FULL raw .sh is here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenVidu/openvidu/master/openvidu-server/docker/openvidu-recording/scripts/composed.sh

****** LINE 79 ********
I REPLACED

```
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -refs 4 -qmin 4 -pix_fmt yuv420p
```

WITH THIS

```
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 -movflags +dash 
-preset ultrafast -crf 28 -refs 4 -qmin 4 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -profile:v main 
-flags -global_header -bufsize 969k 
-hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -g 30 
-start_number 0 -streaming 1 -hls_playlist 1 
-lhls 1 -hls_playlist_type event -f hls
```

It seems weird but it works... my only worry is the "wait x seconds" to create a symlink... what is the server is very busy and the .mp4 gets generated after the x second... it would create issues for playing the stream.

Comment: How do you open/access `NewFile.m3u8`? (In which program? Using which command?). Also, can you change the ".sh" you have? E.g. can you make it either rename the file or create the symlink after `ffmpeg` terminates?

Comment: @fra-san the .m3u8 is accessed via a browser, not a program. If the browser hit a .m3u8 (symlink created before the .mp4) => the browser won't open it. /// I can change the .sh and I tried to create the symlink there: it creates it, but same issue, because it's created before ffmpeg begins, the browser says 404 not found

Comment: "because it's created before `ffmpeg` begins" – Why not after `ffmpeg` terminates?

Comment: Could you update your question to include the part of the script that makes the mp3 and the symlink?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It don't want to wait, see my EDIT 1 in the question, I added more details, it's for live video streaming

Comment: @linux_kettle See EDIT 1 in the question

Comment: What if you use `-f` to set the desired format? It should make `ffmpeg` not rely on the output file extension. Then you should be able to use any extension you want.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I wrote it in the question, I did try to ffmpeg -f hls ...m3u8 but it stops suddenly after less than 20 sec.... when I rechange to .mp4 it don't stop.

Comment: For the record: you wrote you had tried the `m3u8` extension, but you did not mention `-f` (so it may have been without `-f`). Then you edited and `-f` appeared, but it is not clear you tried with `m3u8` extension this time (maybe you didn't). The `composed.sh` you linked to seems very far from minimal (in context of [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659)), so don't expect anyone to deduce from it if you used `-f` with `m3u8` extension or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that i didn't read your whole question but judging from the title this should work:

`while [ ! -f /tmp/originalfile ] ; do sleep 1 ; done ; ln -s /tmp/originalfile /tmp/symlink`

Comment: Note that you don't have to sleep exactly 1 second, feel free to use `sleep 0.1` or lower if you are in a hurry. If you are *really* in a hurry, use `true` instead  of `sleep someseconds`

Comment: There is an unknown (unpredictable) delay between the webhook, the api call and ffmpeg process. Right now I sleep 8 (8 seconds), that's why I was looking for a better solution then sleep(8)..... your answer seem a god way to start, let me do some tests... also, ffmpeg creates a buffer before creating the .mp4

Comment: @Jintor If by "a buffer" you mean an empty file that shouldn't be linked to because it's not a video yet, then the test may be like `file -b --mime-type foo.mp4 | grep -q video/`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried the answer from Garo and it's working very well ;) the buffer was not the issue, I simply needed a way to "wait" for the creation of the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to wait until a file is created in the parent directory:

```
inotifywait -e create /path/to/parent
```